# A question about nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If matrix $A+tB$ is nilpotent for different real values $t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_n$, then are the matrices $A$ and $B$ nilpotent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

An $n\times n$ matrix $C$ is nilpotent if and only if $C^n = 0$. Every entry of $C^n$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $n$ in the entries of $C$. Therefore, every entry of the matrix 
$$(A+tB)^n$$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree at most $n$. If such a polynomial is zero for $n+1$ values, what happens?